# Div-Element don't refresh after dynamic adding of elements

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-app.
On one of my pages i'm adding elements dynamically to a div-element.
The elements are added but i can't see them on the page.
Just after clicking F5 and running the controller-code again i can see them.

Here's the code for adding the elements:

```
    if ($scope.eigenschaften != null) {
        //TODO Eigenschaften in Loop durchgehen und auf panel_dynamic Controls erzeugen
        var panel_dynamic = document.getElementById('panel_dynamic');
        if (panel_dynamic.hasChildNodes()) {
            panel_dynamic.removeChild(panel_dynamic.childNodes[0]);
        }
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        for (n = 0; n <= $scope.eigenschaften.length - 1; n++) {
            // Creates a new div with controls
            var line = document.createElement('div');
            var para = document.createElement('p');
            // Creates a div-row
            var div_row = document.createElement('div');
            div_row.setAttribute('class', 'row');
            // Creates a div-col with label
            var div_col_label = document.createElement('div');
            div_col_label.setAttribute('class', 'col');
            div_col_label.appendChild(CreateLabel('font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;', $scope.eigenschaften[n].name));
            div_row.appendChild(div_col_label);
            // Creates a div-col with control
            var div_col_control = document.createElement('div');
            div_col_control.setAttribute('class', 'col');
            div_col_control.appendChild(CreateTextbox());
            div_row.appendChild(div_col_control);
            // Adds the div-row to the para
            para.appendChild(div_row);
            // Adds the new para to the line
            line.appendChild(para);
            // Adds the new line to the content
            content.appendChild(line);
        }
        // Adds the content-div to panel_dynamic
        panel_dynamic.appendChild(content);
    }
```

"eigenschaften" is an array with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i used the id for my container-div "panel_dynamic" even in another template. And JavaScript was getting the other div by getElementById. Now i have changed the ids and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't triggering change detection. You should add the elements using an `ng-repeat` in your template that's bound to an array or some other iterable on the model instead. Then everytime you add something new to the iterable, it will get added in the view.